# Could some AI Racers be Undercover cops?

Tags: need-for-speed-rivals

In NFS Rivals, as a cop, I can choose an undercover car that resembles those of the racers. While playing as a racer myself (especially offline), I've often wondered if any of the AI racers that I meet in the world could infact be undercover cops. Especially because taking on some of them on a head-to-head challenge seems to drive me straight into a hornet's nest full of cops in wait. And many times, it seems the cops are only trying to attack my car while sparing the AI racer.

Is the concept of an undercover cop only available for human racers in multiplayer mode? Or is it possible for an AI racer (during offline play) to be an undercover cop? If yes, how can I tell?

Comment: This is something NFS has always done, and that is that the cops will always chase you... they always ignore the rest for some reason...

Comment: All cop cars are black, that includes the undercover ones. I haven't come around to play as racer yet, but as a rank 23 cop I haven't seen a single racer using a black car.

Comment: @Nolonar: As a racer, you have the option to customize your car, and that includes painting it with whatever color you choose, and choosing among gloss, metallic, satin and matte as the type of finish. So there you go -- a racer can have 4 different blacks, if he wants. But I get your point -- if an AI racer is black, he's got to be an undercover cop. Hmm... unlikely, but let me give this theory a shot.

Answer (score 1):

No, racers cannot be undercover cops.